# Using Regex to parse Comma Separated List

Tags: regex, csv

I have a list of specific valid values: XX,SX,FC,SC,Jump.

Basically I need to look at user-supplied list of values and if one of the values does not match the above list I will throw an error.  Can I use a regular expression to accomplish this?

Comment: You're going to want to use the 'split' function of whatever language you're using. And what language is that, by the way?

Comment: Indeed using split and sets is a way better solution, since that allows you to actually report which values are not allowed. With a regex you can only generate some very unhelpful error message.

Answer (score 1):

This will match a comma separated list of 5 sequences of alphanumeric characters.

```
[A-Za-z0-9](,[A-Za-z0-9]){4}
```

However, and depending on the language you are using, I'd normally split the string and then check the length of the resulting array. For instance, in **Java**:

```
String csvList = "XX,SX,FC,SC,Jump";
String[] elements = csvList.split(",");
if (elements.length != 5) {
  throw new Exception();
}
```